Most strict DOMPurify configuration?
I used the default DOMPurify (https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/tree/main) configuration for input sanitization in JavaScript, but noticed that tags like "h3" are allowed. I was wondering what the most strict DOMPurify configuration is (to only allow text)? The goal is to prevent XSS.
